# UIView frame bounds not resizing automatically

Tags: xcode, constraints, frame, xib

I am using Xcode 5 with mostly default xib settings for an iOS 7 app.

Whether I run my app in the 4" simulator or the 3.5" simulator, the frame bounds are always 320 x 504 when inspected in the debugger (viewDidLoad):

```
po self.view
<UIView: 0x9cfa990; frame = (0 0; 320 504); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x9cecdd0>>
```

This is fine for the 4" screen but there is some cutoff in the 3.5" screen.

How can I make sure the view resizes on any sized screen, seeing as iPhone 6 is coming out and that will be different as well?

For example, if I have subview inside my view, I know how to pin it to the top and bottom, but what if I want to pin the view itself to the top and bottom of the screen or window itself? What constraints or parameters do I need to set? Can it be done in Interface Builder or only programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

I actually was having the same issue with the iPhone 6 and 6+, where some CALayer modifications weren't registering right for the larger screens. In the end, what worked for me was moving the CALayer modifications to viewDidAppear (the issues persisted even in viewWillAppear). Hope that helps.